# Arduino reading signals from Java and displaying/using them

Tags: java, arduino, rxtx

I've been working on communication between java and arduino lately because I have a project that needs it, so I've been reading a lot about it and started making some progress with it such as sending String from java and reading it in the arduino and using it then sending outputs to java again , anyways after that I had to set a slider in java so I can send values between 0 and 1023 to the arduino while moving it but the problems started to appear here, I created the slider (using JSlider) and used stateChanged method to send the values to the arduino and then the arduino should read the data and report back to java, I've set MinorTickSpacing to 100 so whenever you click on the slider it goes from 0 to 100 and so, the arduino reads data correctly(it reads it 3 times and I don't know why) until it reaches 300 this is the output I see in java (Reading the output from arduino using serialEvent and BufferReader):

```
COM port found:COM3
Port open succesful: COM3
100
100
200
200
200
44
44
44
65533
65533
65533
244
244
```

I clicked 5 times on the slider so it should read 100, 200, 300, 400 & 500 but I see those strange numbers and I don't know why.
Here is my programs for both Java (Used RXTX Library and Eclipse IDE) & Arduino.

Java Program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;                    //BufferedReader makes reading operation efficient
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;         //InputStreamReader decodes a stream of bytes into a character set
import java.io.OutputStream;          //writes stream of bytes into serial port
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;           
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;            //deals with possible events in serial port (eg: data received)
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; //listens to the a possible event on serial port and notifies when it does
import java.util.Enumeration;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;           //all the exceptions.Never mind them for now
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;
import java.util.Scanner;                                   //to get user input of name
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestingGUI implements SerialPortEventListener,ActionListener, ChangeListener {        

    private SerialPort serialPort ;         //defining serial port object
    private CommPortIdentifier portId  = null;       //my COM port
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;    //time in milliseconds
    private static final int BAUD_RATE = 9600; //baud rate to 9600bps
    private BufferedReader input;               //declaring my input buffer
    private OutputStream output;                //declaring output stream
    private String name;        //user input name string
    public static String status;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label,label1;
    JSlider slide;
    JProgressBar progress;
    JButton onButton,offButton,blinkButton;
    Scanner inputName;          //user input name
    public TestingGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(700, 150);
        frame.setTitle("Arduino Test");
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        slide = new JSlider();
        slide.setMinimum(0);
        slide.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        slide.setMaximum(1023);
        slide.setMinorTickSpacing(100);
        slide.setPaintLabels(true);
        slide.setPaintTicks(true);
        slide.setSnapToTicks(true);
        slide.setToolTipText("Move the slider to desired location.");
        slide.setValue(0);
        slide.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
        slide.addChangeListener(this);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        slide.setBounds(10,10, 650, 50);
        panel.add(slide);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    //method initialize
    private void initialize()
    {
        CommPortIdentifier ports = null;      //to browse through each port identified
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); //store all available ports
        while(portEnum.hasMoreElements()) //browse through available ports
        {  
                ports = (CommPortIdentifier)portEnum.nextElement();
             //following line checks whether there is the port i am looking for and whether it is serial
               if(ports.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL&&ports.getName().equals("COM3"))
               { 
                    System.out.println("COM port found:COM3");
                    portId = ports;                  //initialize my port
                    break;                                                                                     
               }
         }
       //if serial port am looking for is not found
        if(portId==null)
        {
            System.out.println("COM port not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }
                            }

    //end of initialize method

    //connect method

    private void portConnect()
    {
        //connect to port
        try
        {
            serialPort = (SerialPort)portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),TIME_OUT);   //down cast the comm port to serial port
                                                                                     //time to wait
            System.out.println("Port open succesful: COM3"); 

            //set serial port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(BAUD_RATE,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        }
        catch(PortInUseException e){
            System.out.println("Port already in use");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e2){
            System.out.println("COM port maybe disconnected");
        }
        catch(UnsupportedCommOperationException e3){
            System.out.println(e3.toString());
        }

        //input and output channels
        try
        {
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
                output =  serialPort.getOutputStream();
                //adding listeners to input and output streams
                serialPort.addEventListener(this);
                serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
                serialPort.notifyOnOutputEmpty(true);
      //defining reader and output stream
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
                            }

    }
    //end of portConncet method
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == slide)
        {
            try {
                int out = slide.getValue();
                output.write(out);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    }
    //readWrite method
    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) 
    { 

        if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) //if data available on serial port
        { 
            try {
            if(input.ready())
            {
                int testInt = input.read();
                System.out.println(testInt);
             }
                } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }

    }
    //end of serialEvent method
    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TestingGUI myTest = new TestingGUI();  //creates an object of the class
        myTest.initialize();
        myTest.portConnect();
    }//end of main method
}// end of  SerialTest
```

and Arduino Program:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available() == 0)
  {

  }
  int test2 = Serial.read();
  Serial.write(test2);
}
```

What should I do to get the correct number and exceed the limit that the arduino shows? (apparently only numbers between 0 and 255 is read correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Arduino `Serial.Read()` documentation: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read calling it returns:

> the first **byte** of incoming serial data available (or -1 if no data is available) - int

By definition, a byte can have a value between 0 and 225, which is why those values work correctly.

When you send value of 300, you experience something called "Arithmetic overflow" - imagine that you count from 0 to 300, but at 255 you start from 0 again, and then you reach 44. Same goes for 500.

I'm not sure why do you get 65533 for 400, it should be 144 (400 [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 256). I'll update the answer if I find out.

Summing up - you shouldn't send or expect values outside 0-255 range. If you want to sent bigger number, divide it into bytes and assemble back on the other side of communication channel.

Comment: Thanks for the input that really explained a lot as I was really confused about what was happening there , but is there any other method to send the data correctly and not having to do that dividing thing ? sending 4 bytes (a whole integer) instead of 1 byte?

and also can you explain to me please why Arduino reads the data 3 times everytime there is an input? I used while(Serial.available() == 0) to stop that but nothing seems to help :/

Comment: I don't know about any way of sending whole integer through serial port, but it's not a bug, it's a feature. It's wiser to break integer into four bytes using operators `%` and `>>` and reassemble it back on the other side with operators `*` and `<<`, because it allows you to avoid problems with endianness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: As to multiple readings, the code on Arduino side is not the cause. I suspect that you capture more events than you expect. Try adding `System.out.println("Slide event");` after line `int out = slide.getValue();`, then we will know for sure.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I was away from my computer couldn't get back to the project until now, about breaking the integer I never did that I'll  read about it and do it thanks.  
and for the multiple reading I did what you said and this is my output after 5 clicks :  
[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/etdlko2.png)    
This is driving me crazy ! :/

Comment: Try remembering last value as a private field and call `output.write(out);` only if `out` is different than remembered value.